# localstorage token not found with put request? (node, react, mongodb)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I have an api where I get the profile details from the backend. This one works perfectly.

```
componentDidMount() {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token) {
            this.setState({ loading: true });
            axios.get('/api/getUser', { headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': token } }).then((res) =>
                this.setState({
                    name: res.data.name,
                    date: res.data.date,
                    age: res.data.age,
                    gender: res.data.gender,
                    location: res.data.location,
                    bio: res.data.bio,
                    image: res.data.image,
                    loading: false,
                })
            );
        }
    }
```

However, **when I send a put request to update the profile details, the token isn't found**... I am logged in of course.

```
updateDone(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token) {
            this.setState({ loading: true });
            axios
                .put(`/api/updateProfile/5ed9d3897e516616600eb692`, { headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': token } })
                .then((res) =>
                    this.setState({
                        name: res.data.name,
                        loading: false,
                    })
                );
        }
    }
```

What's going on? In Postman, it works, I already tested it.

Comment: Well that means something is deleting token. Perhaps you could share us that as well

Comment: it's funny because on the backend it works, it goes through in Postman... and I don't know what is deleting the token on the client side. this put request is almost exactly the same as the get request in the componentDidMount()

Comment: can  you try it on incognito mode and see if it works ??

Comment: just tried, same :(

Comment: I have the solution, I will put it in an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to reformat to this an async function:

```
updateDone = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
        if (token) {
            this.setState({ loading: true });
            await axios({
                method: 'PUT',
                url: '/api/updateProfile/5ed9d3897e516616600eb692',
                data: this.state,
                headers: { Accept: 'application/json', 'X-Auth-Token': token },
            }).then((res) =>
                this.setState({
                    name: this.state.name,
                    loading: false,
                })
            );
        }
    };
```

I just don't understand why?